# Resistor in Pi-filter

Tags: resistors, passive-filter

I have a basic question on the position of a resistor with respect to a pi-filter and hope you clarify my confusion.

Consider these two circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUTODf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is the position of the resistor R1 imporant here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome. *"It depends."* Please clarify what you wish to achieve with the Pi Filter and also with that additional resistor.

Comment: Welcome! In your second case, the C1 capacitor will have no function as it's in parallel with an ideal voltage source.

Comment: There is always some resistance even if it is small...

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. These electronics are used in a setup I work with. It is mainly used to filter out any spikes in the voltage to protect delicate samples which are connected to the right part of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @winny, but I do not fully understand what you mean? Why doesn't C1 have a function when considering no parasitic resistance in the second circuit?

Comment: Pi filters are mainly used to provide impedance matching so, both resistors are relevant. Your first circuit (if not used to impedance match) is not really a pi filter but a 3rd order low pass filter.

Comment: Because the voltage source is _ideal_. You can make C1 as large or small as you want but it won’t have any effect on the output.

Comment: @winny Thanks! I see now

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. Why is it not really a pi-filter? If I search online for the circuit of a pi-filter, it is exactly the circuit inside the dashed box.

Comment: What you have inside your red dashed box might be a pi filter in the first example but certainly is not a pi filter in your 2nd circuit. It's only a pi filter if it's placed in a circuit that is intended to use it as a pi filter. On-line resources are particularly bad in this respect. A pi filter is certainly more than just stringing together 3 components in a particular way. I'm right about this so no need to argue!!

Answer (score 1):

If the left side is a voltage source, and the load is connected to the right side, and you wish to apply a stable voltage to the load, then:

- The first circuit is a 3rd order lowpass, whereas the second circuit is only a 2nd order lowpass.
- "Voltage spikes" at high frequency will be thus quenched more with the first circuit.
- If actual spikes (such as ESD) are your problem, then I suggest adding TVS diodes to the mix

Comment: Thanks for your answer ansd your suggestion! There are still some things I do not fully understand, though: Why is the first circuit a 3rd order while the second circuit is only a 2nd order filter? I see that in the first circuit, the R1 and C1 make up a 1st-order low pass filter. But do L1 and C2 not make another, finally having a 2nd order low pass filter, instead of a 3rd?

Comment: @JH0894 LC filters are by themselves already 2nd order filters.

Comment: I see, that clarifies it. Thanks!